# Linux C program restart itself after a delay

Tags: c, linux, bash, petalinux

I have an embedded system running petalinux 2021.2 and running my application "my_app". I need to be able to send it a command to update itself with a new compiled binary. My app should respond that it is about to update and then restart itself.

I figured I would do it like this:

```
/* Updated binary my_app has already been copied to /usr/bin */
char* command = "( sleep 3; killall -2 my_app; sleep 3; my_app) &";

/* Start the update process */
system(command);

/* Respond to user */
sendUpdateResponse();

......
/* Eventually SIGINT is sent and app cleans up and exits */
```

Unfortunately when my app starts again it does not work properly, specifically the servers it creates don't work as expected. I also notice two new processes are running:

1. sh -c ( sleep 3; killall -2 my_app; sleep 3; my_app) &
2. my_app

However, if I just use ctrl^c to quit the program and then run it again from the command line it works great. I can do this any number of times with no issue. Something about the way I am having it restart itself with a background process is causing issues.

I am sure this is a very dumb way to do this, any suggestions are much appreciated.

Edit: Some more info

I can start process like so: my_app &

I can then run: (sleep 3; killall -2 my_app; sleep 3; my_app) &

No problem here, working as expected. So it has to be something about the fact that the process is the one calling this command

Comment: Is the update copying the new executable on top of the old one, without deleting (or renaming) the old one first?  If so, don't do that.  Any part of the original, running process that was swapped out (or never actually mapped because it wasn't needed yet - such as the `exit()` code path....) will be overwritten by the update process.

Comment: I am deleting the file /usr/bin/my_app and then copying my_app to /usr/bin

Comment: Telegram on Linux does this by having a separate updater executable, which the main one launches and shuts down before being overwritten.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, is this not what I am kind of already doing by running that short script as a background process? If I were to create an updater process, how would I start it from my app without use of system plus & ?

Comment: Any reason `execvp( argv[0], argv );` wouldn't do?

Comment: Good idea, trying this out

Comment: I wouldn't do this with a background process and killall. I would catch SIGINT in the application my_app and exit if received. A shell script would handle updates and restart my_app as needed. Background processes and timing are messy as you've seen

Comment: my app is catching SIGINT and cleaning up and exiting once received. my app is trying to start  a shell script to handle the update

Comment: Just to throw in my own two cents having worked with petalinux doing a similar thing, my system has a script/app pair that starts on boot and waits for an `inotify` event of an update file being written to a certain directory, at which point it can kill the running binary, copy in the new file from tmp location, and restart the process. That has worked like a charm for me with petalinux; we have most of linux there, might as well use it

Comment: @alexv9 Exactly how are you doing the cleanup and starting that shell script?  If you're doing it from within you signal handler, that might be causing your issues - there's not much you can safely do in a signal handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your comments, they lead me to the answer.

The problem was that when I run the updating script it is running as a child process meaning all open file descriptors are inherited by the child process.

The child process sends SIGINT to the running app and the app closes all of its descriptors. The child process then starts the new updated version of the app, however, the app is now running with all the opened descriptors it inherited. This was causing problems. To fix, I had to follow these steps:

1. When update command received, fork()
2. Child process will then need to close all file descriptors (except in, out, err) and then use execl() to run the updating script
3. Updating script sends SIGINT to the app, app closes
4. Updating script starts new version of the app

App is now running from a clean slate with only stdin, stderr, and stdout open. Now it works great